# writing tables to Postgresql using rPostgreSQL when the database name is all capital letters

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a database in PostgreSQL which is named `DATA` in all caps. When I try to write an R data.frame to this database using RPostgreSQL like so:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), host="myhost", 
                 user= "postgres", password="myPass", dbname="DATA")
dbWriteTable(con, "test", myDf)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in
)
[1] FALSE
```

However I notice that if I go to Postgresql and change the database name to `data` (lower case) and then change the script to call `dbname="data"` then it works like a charm.

I looked through the documentation for rPostgreSQL and the only mention of case I saw had to do with field names being case sensitive.

So my questions are:

1. Is this behavior is expected?
2. In my situation I control the DB so I can rename the database at will. How would I work around this behavior if I could not rename the database to all lower case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were definitely issues with *tables* in upper-case. In think we handle that now:
Try quoting it as "DATA" and it should go through. Unquoted table identifier all get lower-cased.

Your issue is having the entire database in uppercase.  It may also work with quoting, maybe even with `'\"DATA\"'` as an argument to dbConnect.

Otherwise, reproducible examples on the list are best, and with some luck, Tomoaki will find a fix for your problem.

Oh, and we spell it like the package: RPostgreSQL with capital arrrrrrr, especially today on talk like a piRate day.

**Edit:**  Looks like there is simply no issue with current versions on Ubuntu 11.04:

First, create `DATA`

```
edd@max:~$ createdb DATA
edd@max:~$ psql DATA
psql (8.4.8)
Type "help" for help.

DATA=# \q
edd@max:~$
```

Second, and in R, connect and save some data:

```
R> library(RPostgreSQL)
R> con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), host="localhost", user= "edd", 
+                   password=".....", dbname="DATA")
R> con
<PostgreSQLConnection:(21936,0)> 
R> dbWriteTable(con, "quicktest", cars)
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Third, check for content in `DATA`:

```
DATA=# select * from quicktest limit 5;
 row_names | speed | dist 
-----------+-------+------
 1         |     4 |    2
 2         |     4 |   10
 3         |     7 |    4
 4         |     7 |   22
 5         |     8 |   16
(5 rows)

DATA=#
```

Looking good to me.

Comment: '\"DATA\"' looks promising. I'll test that in a bit. Thanks, as always, for the super fast response.

Comment: I'm running a version of rPostgreSQL which I built on Mac OS 10.7. It is possible that I built a previous version. I'll build from the latest source and test.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel: dbwrite table is very clear thank you. i have a small question regarding inserting dataframe into a table(database). I have a table with name "bank1" and it already contains some data. i have a dataframe in R with name "df1" which contains the same data (similar no of columns and column names). Now i want to update bank1 with df1. could you please tell me how can i do it